# Отправка смс в телефон заполнившего анкету (Пример: Спасибо что заполнили анкету)

Tags: php, javascript, html, sms

Всем привет!
 Кто работал с **api**-шками (sms.ru)? В анкете нужно обязательно заполнить номер телефона. После отправки анкеты нужно чтобы пришло смс сообщение на номер того кто заполнял анкету. Как это сделать? Кто сталкивался? 
Большой Рахмет!

Comment: я помню делал нечто подобное, никаких проблем не встречал. почитай документацию на sms.ru, там всё должно быть подробно описано. а в вопросе вопроса как такового нет, минимум конкретики. будут проблемы с внедрением - вот тогда добро пожаловать

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне на сайте [sms.ru](http://sms.ru) очень хорошо описан [API](http://sms.ru/api/send), есть множество вариантов отправки: GET, POST, CURL.

Отправка возможна даже простейшим GET запросом:

```
https://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=[Ваш api_id]&to=[Номер телефона]&msg=[Ваше сообщение]
```

Нужно задавать более конкретный вопрос! Не совсем понятно что именно Вы хотите. Не знаете как отправить смс при помощи [API](http://sms.ru/api/send), или что-то ещё. Было бы не плохо увидеть пример кода.